# Use Jedis instance in Repository class - Dropwizard

Tags: java, jersey, dropwizard, jedis

I am using Dropwizard and https://github.com/benjamin-bader/droptools/tree/master/dropwizard-redis bundle to connect to Redis. This bundle adds a Jedis instance to the Context each time a new request comes in. (Accessible via @Context annotation). I want to be able to use this Jedis instance along with some other dependencies injected by Guice.

My Repository class look like this:

```
public class RedisRepository implements Repository {

   private RedisManager redisManager;
   private Jedis jedis;

   @Inject
   public RedisConfigurationRepository(RedisManager redisManager, Jedis 
          jedis) {
       this.redisManager = redisManager;
       this.jedis = jedis;

   }

}
```

But, `jedis` property is not injectable because it's not being managed by Guice. If I add the Context annotation, it does not get injected because of a problem mixing Jersey and Guice injections.

One solution is to inject the Jedis property at the Resource classes and pass it from the Resource to the Repository classes but that does not seem very well designed.

Another solution is to avoid using this Dropwizard bundle and configure a JedisPool, inject it in the Repository classes and create resources as needed. But, per my understanding, what is cool from this bundle is that it creates a Jedis instance per request and free the resource once the connection has been finished. If I don't use it I would have to handle the Redis connection lifecycle by myself.

What are my options besides these?

Comment: You can just use HK2 DI. If you configure the repository with HK2 (which is fairly simple), it would work.